# Variable Range not recognized as a property of Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use both worksheets and ranges as variables, but I'm having some problems.
If I declare a worksheet as a variable and then use the range property it works just fine.
However, when I declare a variable Range and try to use it reference it, it throws me the error 438, object doesn't have property or method.

```
   Sub try()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Code")
    
    ws.Range("A3", "B6").Value = "sheets"
    
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("D1", "F3")
    
    Worksheets("DATOS").r.Value = "ranges"
End Sub
```

My end goal would be to have both the Worksheet and the range as variables, so I could reference it such as

`ws.r.Value = "123"`

Thanks in advance, I hope my question isn't too basic and you can help me.

Comment: If you are setting `r` to be `Range("D1", "F3")` of `WorkSheets("DATOS")` then you should do this `Set r = Worksheets("DATOS").Range("D1", "F3")` Then you set its value like this: `r.Value = "ranges"`

Comment: Hello Raymond. I'm not trying to set r to be the range in that specific worksheet, it was just an example. What I'm trying to do is use the same range "r", in many different worksheets, such as "Datos" or "Code"

Comment: @Irving In this case, you should store the range `"D1:F3"` as a string then you call it like this `Worksheets("DATOS").Range(r).Value = "ranges"`, `Worksheets("Code").Range(r).Value = "ranges"`, so `r` represent the range but in string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a `Range` object, it is not a universal cell address to be used like what you did, each `Range` refers to a specific Worksheet that you can see under its `Worksheet` property. ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.worksheet))

You did not specify the Worksheet in `Set r = Range("D1", "F3")` so VBA assumes that you are referring to the `ActiveSheet` which can be anything. (which is also why you are recommended to always fully qualify your range reference)

As mentioned in your comment - Since your objective is to use the same range for multiple worksheets, you can define the range address in a `String` variable and use that variable as shown below:

```
Sub try()   
    Const r As String = "D1:F3"
    
    Worksheets("DATOS").Range(r).Value = "ranges"
    Worksheets("Code").Range(r).Value = "ranges"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use range variable in this way. Rather qualify range mentioning sheet name. Try below codes.

Try below codes.

```
Sub try()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Code")
    
    ws.Range("A3", "B6").Value = "sheets"
    
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Worksheets("DATOS").Range("D1", "F3")
    
    r = "ranges"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to refer to the range in the way you want.

If you want to use a VBA variable to refer to ranges, you can do this:

```
' Get a range
Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng1 = Sht.Range("A2:B2")
' Set the contents of another range to the same value
Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Rng2 = Sht2.Range("C2:D2")
Rng2.value = Rng1.Value
```

You already seem to have a grasp of doing it this way.

If you want to refer to a range by a name, here is a method that creates a named range:

```
' Delete the named range if it exists and create it again.
Sub CreateNamedRange(Wbk As Workbook, Txt As String, Rng As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Wbk.Names(Txt).Delete
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wbk.Names.Add Txt, Rng
End Sub
```

Here we create a named range *Name1* and retrieve it using *Sht.Range("Name1")*:

```
Sub CreateNamedRangeAndUseIt()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
   
    ' Set the value of the range to 42
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("A2")
    Rng.Value = 42
    
    ' Create a name for the range
    CreateNamedRange ThisWorkbook, "Name1", Rng
    
    ' Activate some other sheet to make sure it works when the
    ' sheet with the named range is not active.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    ' Get the named range and output the value of the range to the
    ' immediate window.
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("Name1")
    ' This would also work, even though the named range does not
    ' exist on Sheet1:
    '     Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Name1")
    ' Or this (provided you don't have several workbooks open and
    ' another workbook is selected)
    '     Set Rng = Range("Name1")
    Debug.Print Rng.Value
    
    ' Then select the range.
    ' We must activate the sheet first to select ranges in it.
    Rng.Worksheet.Activate
    Rng.Select
End Sub
```

The named range will still exist if you close and reopen the workbook, provided you save the workbook before closing it. So you only need to name the range once.